# How to make custom uitypes display in dropdown list when i am creating custom filed

Tags: types, vtiger, vtigercrm, custom-field-type

I have created custom UI-types for vtiger 7. They work perfectly fine. They are displayed in layout-editor on existing custom fields and on needed pages. But I don't know how to make them display in the dropdown list when I am creating a new custom filed. Don't know how to do this. Didn`t find anything on google.

I`ve created PHP classes for UI-type, templates in folders 'layout' and 'v7/layout'. Added them to db 'field type' table, changed UI-type in 'field' table for a few fields.

Uitypes must be displayed in the dropdown list when I am creating a new custom filed, but they don't.

Comment: This might help you : http://vtiger-crm.2324883.n4.nabble.com/vTiger-6-New-UIType-tt4994.html#a4997

Answer (score 0):

Modify the follwoing file and add your custom uitype name:

```
Class: Settings_LayoutEditor_Module_Model
Method: getAddSupportedFieldTypes
Lines: 91-96
File: modules/Settings/LayoutEditor/models/Module.php
```